# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'typing_extensions'

Tags: python, django

i am working in a blog site with django.
my project urls.py code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from.import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.index,name="home"),
    path('login/',views.authlogin,name="login"),
    path('signup/',views.signup,name="signup"),
    path('contact/',views.contact,name="contact"),
    path('about/',views.about,name="about"),
    path('logout/',views.authlogout,name='logout'),
    path('dashboard/',views.dashboard,name='dashboard'),
    path('updatepost/<int:id>',views.update_post,name='updatepost'),
    path('addpost/',views.add_post,name='addpost'),
    path('delete/<int:id>',views.delete_post,name='deletepost'),
]
```

but it shows me

```
 File "C:\Users\ABU RAYHAN\Desktop\projects\miniblog\blog\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from.import views
  File "C:\Users\ABU RAYHAN\Desktop\projects\miniblog\blog\views.py", line 1, in <module>
    from typing_extensions import Required
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'typing_extensions'
```

i am new here pardon my mistake.

Answer (score 38):

There must be an import from [typing-extensions](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) module in blog\views.py file on line 1

in your code.
Use this command to install it

> `pip install typing-extensions`

after that this issue will be resolved.

Comment: Very frustrated, built-in modules don't providing own dependencies :(

Comment: If you need specific version `pip3 install typing-extensions==3.10.0.0`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error.

Mine came from *models.py*

***models.py***

```
from typing_extensions import Required
from django.db import models


class nameOfModel(models.Model):
    nameOfField = models.CharField(max_length=255, Required=True)
```

Because I used `Required=True`, VSCode added automatically `from typing_extensions import Required`.

So I did this instead.

***models.py***

```
from django.db import models


class nameOfModel(models.Model):
    nameOfField = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with the forms.Textarea wich cannot accept required, so it calls for import from typing-extensions and this make the problem